# Calculating values based on dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a dynamic aggregation based on fields. The only difference is that it's not a table but a div block.

**What I am trying to accomplish**

On button click add field, the content from the template is cloned ( it's like a table row ), this part is fully working.

The code is supposed to count the values, for each row add some fields. I used keyup function to keep it updated all time.

**Why is it not working?**

Well I was not able to get it working like such .each of i_row or template contains fields `p_cnetto[] p_pvat[] p_ilosc[]` ( quantitiy )

Because I can't read row wise - I tried many things but apparently did something bad it only counts curr_net value and it's still not the way it should be.

Decimal values should be acceptable : example 2222.00

**How it should work?**

1. Add a row
2. Summing row part [ not really need to display row aggregation ]:

   - curr_netto = get this row `p_cnetto[]` value multiply by `p_ilosc[]`
   - curr_brutto = get this row `(p_cnetto[]  * p_pvat[]) / 100 * p_ilosc[]`

At the end it should calculate a grand total of all rows for as total_netto,total_brutto - could be in console.log

Thanks for any tips.

[`JsFiddle Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/rftoLruo/7/)

```html
     <!-- statistic block --->
<div id="curr_netto"></div>
<div id="curr_brutto"></div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-add-panel mt-5" type="button"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add field</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12" id="extra_group">

    <!-- s -->

    <div class="widget widget2 card template mb-2 bg-light-blue-50" style="display: none;">
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <div class="row i_row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_nazwa[]" class="form-control"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
              <label>Qty</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_ilosc[]" class="form-control p_ilosc"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
              <label>Unit</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="p_unit[]">
                <option value="Kg">Kilogram</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
              <label>Net</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_cnetto[]" class="form-control p_cnetto"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group pmd-textfield pmd-textfield-floating-label">
              <label>VAT</label>
              <input type="text" name="p_pvat[]" class="form-control p_pvat"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <div class="subtot"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-add-panel rh mt-5 ml-3"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> Del</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <!-- s -->
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer, this works for me

```
$(document).bind("keyup change", function (e) {
            var pbrutto = 0;
            var wartosc_vat = 0;
            var cnetto = 0;

            jQuery('#extra_group .template').each(function () {

                var qty_field_current = (Number(jQuery(this).find('.p_ilosc').val()));
                var vatfield_current = (Number(jQuery(this).find('.p_pvat').val()));
                var nettofield_current = (Number(jQuery(this).find('.p_cnetto').val().replace("Zł ", "").replace(",", "")));
                cnetto = cnetto + (nettofield_current * qty_field_current);
                wartosc_vat = wartosc_vat + (nettofield_current * vatfield_current) / 100;
                wartosc_vat = wartosc_vat * qty_field_current;

            });

            pbrutto = cnetto + wartosc_vat;
            $("#curr_brutto").html("Brutto : " + pbrutto + " zł");
            $("#curr_netto").html("Netto : " + cnetto + " zł");
            $("#curr_vat").html("Vat : " + wartosc_vat + " zł");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

below code will loop through individual block and get the values.

```
$(document).keyup(function() {

   // desired calculation : for curr_netto is [name='p_cnetto[]']" * [name="p_pvat[]"]
   // curr_brutto = ([name='p_cnetto[]']" * [name="p_pvat[]"]) / 100 * name="p_ilosc[]"
   var cnetto = 0;
   var pnetto = 0;
   jQuery('#extra_group .template').each(function(){
       var resetVar = (Number(jQuery(this).find('.p_cnetto').val())    * Number(jQuery(this).find('.p_pvat').val()));
       cnetto = cnetto + resetVar;

       pnetto = pnetto + ((resetVar / 100) * Number(jQuery(this).find('.p_cnetto').val()));
   });

   $("#curr_netto").html("Netto : " + cnetto + " -- " + pnetto)
   console.log(cnetto);
 });
```

@Kavvson Empcraft also updated your jsfiddle - you can check the output